# Print on envelopes using Ghostscript with VB.NET Windows Form Application

Tags: vb.net, pdf, printing, ghostscript

I need to print a two page PDF. The 1st page needs to be for an envelope and then the 2nd page will need to print a regular piece of paper like normal. It can be in two separate PDF's so my question is: How can I set the printer to use envelope using Ghostscript? Has anyone ever done this? I couldnt find the exact parameter I needed in order to accomplish this. I have tried several different things and it still prints a regular sheet of paper and wont use the envelope tray that holds all the envelopes. It looks like I need to change to the MediaType but I do not know the parameter for that. Any ideas? Suggestions on how to accomplish this using VB.NET/C#? Heres my code that I have without any parameters dealing with envelopes. My envelope size is 9.5 x 4.15 inches. Just a standard envelope. I have tried setting -sPAPERSIZE=c6 in hopes that this would be close enough to trigger the envelope tray but still no luck.

```
        Dim psInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
        psInfo.Arguments = String.Format(" -dPrinted -dNoCancel=true -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -noquery -all -dNumCopies=1 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile=""%printer%{0}"" ""{1}""", printername, pdfFileName)
        psInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.15\bin\gswin64c.exe"
        psInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        psInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        psInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Dim p As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psInfo)
        Dim s As String = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd &      p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000)
        p.WaitForExit(15000)
        If p.HasExited = False Then
            p.Kill()
        End If
```

Comment: I think this could be printer specific - if you have a ppd file for the printer you could inspect it and check the code that is set into the postscript to select the envelope tray

Answer (score 0):

When using the mswinpr2 device, most of the Ghostscript command line is more or less unrelated to the physical printer. The various command line options affect the behaviour of the Ghostscript PostScript interpreter, but only the device-specific parameters will affect the device.

The mswinpr2 device does not alter the tray/media selection of the device (unless you set it  up to query the user for the print properties on each print). So it uses the printer defaults instead.

In order to get it to print on envelope media, you will need to set the printer default setting to envelope.

Comment: the only problem with setting its default to envelope is that they use it for other print jobs as well not just envelopes so thats where i need to be able to toggle which tray i need it to use. Any ideas on how to do this? Is there another tool i can use?

Comment: You cannot do what you are asking with the mswinpr2 devioce, its as simple as that, it was never intended to be an unattended print manager. I've no doubt that you can modify the device to do what you want, its a  simple matter of coding. Alternatives ? Well there's the Adobe PDF Print Engine, no doubt there are many other solutions for printing PDF files on Windows.

Comment: i actually use ghostscript with a backoffice app that i have with a timer on it that ticks every second. It has worked great now for years so as soon as they print something from our web page it automatically gets sent to their printer. Works like a charm so it can be done just not for envelope.